# Why is $x'=\lambda x$ considered stiff for $\lambda<0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the ODE $x'(t)=\lambda x(t)$, $x(0)=1$ for $t\in[0,1]$, with $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. Applying the explicit Euler method yields approximations $x_N$ with $x_N(i/N)=(1+\frac{\lambda}{N})^i$, $i\in\{0,\dots,N\}$.

The relative error to the exact solution $x(t)=\exp(\lambda t)$ is therefore
$$
\epsilon_N(i/N)=\frac{\exp(\lambda i/N)-(1+\frac{\lambda}{N})^i}{\exp(\lambda i/N)}\\
=1-(1+\frac{\lambda}{N})^i\exp(-\lambda i/N)=1-\exp(i\log(1+\frac{\lambda}{N})-i\lambda/N)=1-\exp(-i\xi^2)
$$
for some $\xi\in[0,|\lambda|/N]$ (as long as $N>-\lambda$). Therefore, $\sup_{i=1}^N|\epsilon_N|\leq \alpha$ requires (with $0<\alpha<1$ fixed and $\lambda\to \infty$) that $N\sim\lambda^2$.

In the above derivation, the sign of $\lambda$ only appears once, when we require $N>-\lambda$ (which only is restrictive when $\lambda<0$). However, at the end we get $N\sim\lambda^2$ anyway. Therefore, I don't understand why the problem is considered stiff for $\lambda<0$ but not for $\lambda>0$.

Comment: This: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation may be relevant? (the example is pretty much exactly your case). I've only had a brief look but I'd tend to agree with your development, if $|\lambda|$ is large, you will need very small step-sizes for EE.

Answer (score 1):

In hindsight, I think the answer is that stiffness is simply not about relative accuracy over a finite horizon but about absolute accuracy, and more importantly, absolute accuracy over long time spans. In a multi-dimensional stable dynamical system it is maybe more clear that there is interesting qualitative behavior (e.g. which components, dominate, is their oscillation between components etc) to observe even when there are large relative errors, especially if those large relative errors are in components that simply quickly decay to zero and contribute nothing interesting to the system

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Why do you think so? The question is soft, so the answer is soft.